# UnsatisfiedDependencyException When injecting a Spring Component into Jersey 2.22.1

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jersey-2.0, weblogic12c, spring-web

Technologies used:
Spring Boot 4.2.4-RELEASE 
Jersey 2.x (spring boot starter version)
Deployed on Weblogic 12.1.3

I'm experiencing a  org.glassfish.hk2.api.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: There was no object available for injection at Injectee error when I try to inject a Spring managed resource.

pom.xml

```
<parent>
    <artifactId>sl-locates-ui-appsrv</artifactId>
    <groupId>com.db.sl</groupId>
    <version>0.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>

<properties>
    <start-class>com.db.sl.config.Application</start-class>
</properties>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
            <configuration>
                <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>${jdk.version}</source>
                <target>${jdk.version}</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
    </dependency>


    <!-- Phoenix Specific -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.db.sl</groupId>
        <artifactId>sl-locates-ftp-core</artifactId>
        <version>${sl-locates-ftp-core.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
                <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.db.gef</groupId>
        <artifactId>SLUtils</artifactId>
        <version>${slutils.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sybase</groupId>
        <artifactId>jconn4</artifactId>
        <version>${jconn4.version}</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Spring -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jersey</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

weblogic.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wls:weblogic-web-app xmlns:wls="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app"
                  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                  xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app/1.4/weblogic-web-app.xsd">
<wls:weblogic-version>12.1.3</wls:weblogic-version>
<wls:library-ref>
    <library-name>jax-rs</library-name>
    <specification-version>2.0</specification-version>
    <exact-match>false</exact-match>
</wls:library-ref>

<wls:container-descriptor>
    <wls:prefer-application-packages>
        <wls:package-name>org.apache.log4j.*</wls:package-name>
        <wls:package-name>org.slf4j</wls:package-name>
    </wls:prefer-application-packages>
</wls:container-descriptor>
```

This is my SpringBootApplication class

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
}

/*protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder builder) {
    return builder.sources(Application.class, SpringConfiguration.class);
}*/

@Bean
public ServletContainer jerseyServlet() {
    return new ServletContainer();
}

@Bean
public ServletRegistrationBean jerseyServletRegistration() {
    ServletRegistrationBean registration = new ServletRegistrationBean(jerseyServlet());
    Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<String,String>();
    params.put("contextClass","org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext");
    params.put("contextConfigLocation", "com.db.sl.config.SpringConfiguration");
    registration.setInitParameters(params);
    return registration;
}
}
```

Config class for Jersey

```
@Named
@ApplicationPath("/rest")
public class JerseyConfig extends ResourceConfig {
    public JerseyConfig() {
        packages(true, "com.db.sl");
        register(LocatesRestEndPoint.class);
    }
}
```

Config class for Spring

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan("com.db.sl")
public class SpringConfiguration {

@Bean
@Inject
LocatesDAO createLoactesDAO(DataSource dataSource) {
    System.out.println("DataSource: " + dataSource.toString());
    return new LocatesDAOImpl(dataSource);
}
}
```

And finally the class where the error occurs

```
@Named
@Path("/locates")
public class LocatesRestEndPoint {

@Inject
private LocatesRequestService requestsService;

@GET
@Path("/requests/{customerKey}")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public LocatesWebResponse getFileRequestsWith(@PathParam("customerId") String customerId) throws Exception {
    log.info("Facilitating request for Locates File Requests with customer key " + customerId);

    return requestsService.getLocateRequests(customerId);
}
}
```

I had been deploying this project onto tomcat but our work environment requires weblogic to be used. The project works on tomcat but on weblogic I don't even have the spring banner being displayed on deployment. I've checked all the logs I could find and have found no other error conditions. The stack trace I do have is:

```
####<Jan 25, 2016 5:09:25 PM EST> <Error> <HTTP> <USRDUDT808849>     <AdminServer> <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '4' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <> <1453759765485> <BEA-101017> <[ServletContext@2070365887[app:sl-locates-ui-appsrv-rest-0.0.0-SNAPSHOT module:sl-locates-ui-appsrv-rest-0.0.0-SNAPSHOT.war path:null spec-version:3.0], request: weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl@15ba67aa[
GET /sl-locates-ui-appsrv-rest-0.0.0-SNAPSHOT/rest/locates/requests/with-date/2010-02-03 HTTP/1.1
Accept: text/html, application/xhtml+xml, */*
Accept-Language: en-US
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
DNT: 1
Connection: Keep-Alive

]] Root cause of ServletException.
A MultiException has 3 exceptions.  They are:
1. org.glassfish.hk2.api.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: There was no object available for injection at Injectee(requiredType=LocatesRequestService,parent=LocatesRestEndPoint,qualifiers={}),position=-1,optional=false,self=false,unqualified=null,1669020655)
2. java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: While attempting to resolve the dependencies of com.db.sl.appsrv.endpoints.LocatesRestEndPoint errors were found
3. java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to perform operation: resolve on com.db.sl.appsrv.endpoints.LocatesRestEndPoint

at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Collector.throwIfErrors(Collector.java:88)
at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.resolveAllDependencies(ClazzCreator.java:269)
at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.create(ClazzCreator.java:413)
at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.create(SystemDescriptor.java:456)
at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.findOrCreate(RequestScope.java:158)
at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.createService(Utilities.java:2488)
at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.getService(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:629)
at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.getService(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:614)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.Injections.getOrCreate(Injections.java:173)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.MethodHandler$ClassBasedMethodHandler.getInstance(MethodHandler.java:185)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.PushMethodHandlerRouter.apply(PushMethodHandlerRouter.java:103)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage._apply(RoutingStage.java:128)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage._apply(RoutingStage.java:131)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage._apply(RoutingStage.java:131)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage._apply(RoutingStage.java:131)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage._apply(RoutingStage.java:131)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage.apply(RoutingStage.java:110)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage.apply(RoutingStage.java:65)
at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.Stages.process(Stages.java:197)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$1.run(ServerRuntime.java:250)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)
at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:318)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:236)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:1010)
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:373)
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:382)
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:345)
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:220)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:280)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:254)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:136)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:346)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:243)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3432)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3402)
at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSubjectHandle.run(WlsSubjectHandle.java:57)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.doSecuredExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2285)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2201)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2179)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1572)
at weblogic.servlet.provider.ContainerSupportProviderImpl$WlsRequestExecutor.run(ContainerSupportProviderImpl.java:255)
at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:311)
at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:263)
```

Caused By: org.glassfish.hk2.api.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: There was no object available for injection at Injectee(requiredType=LocatesRequestService,parent=LocatesRestEndPoint,qualifiers={}),position=-1,optional=false,self=false,unqualified=null,1669020655)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ThreeThirtyResolver.resolve(ThreeThirtyResolver.java:74)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.resolve(ClazzCreator.java:231)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.resolveAllDependencies(ClazzCreator.java:254)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.create(ClazzCreator.java:413)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.create(SystemDescriptor.java:456)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.findOrCreate(RequestScope.java:158)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.createService(Utilities.java:2488)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.getService(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:629)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.getService(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:614)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.Injections.getOrCreate(Injections.java:173)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.MethodHandler$ClassBasedMethodHandler.getInstance(MethodHandler.java:185)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.PushMethodHandlerRouter.apply(PushMethodHandlerRouter.java:103)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage._apply(RoutingStage.java:128)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage._apply(RoutingStage.java:131)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage._apply(RoutingStage.java:131)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage._apply(RoutingStage.java:131)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage._apply(RoutingStage.java:131)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage.apply(RoutingStage.java:110)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage.apply(RoutingStage.java:65)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.Stages.process(Stages.java:197)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$1.run(ServerRuntime.java:250)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:318)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:236)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:1010)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:373)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:382)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:345)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:220)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:280)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:254)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:136)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:346)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:243)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3432)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3402)
    at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
    at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSubjectHandle.run(WlsSubjectHandle.java:57)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.doSecuredExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2285)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2201)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2179)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1572)
    at weblogic.servlet.provider.ContainerSupportProviderImpl$WlsRequestExecutor.run(ContainerSupportProviderImpl.java:255)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:311)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:263)

> 

Comment: Seems odd to me that all your dependencies are `provided`

Comment: All the dependencies will be available on the class path on our deployment server. I'm still fairly new to maven but was under the impression that this would keep the war size small. It also prevents a bunch of class definition exceptions from coming up.

Comment: Any luck on this?  Additionally, there are some issues with weblogic and it's "helpfulness" with providing files, but generally you want to bundle the class dependencies in with the war.